# How to get data from each KVP

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I've got list imported from PHP to Unity by using WWW. 
WWW.text contains this:

```
[
    {
        "playerId": "1",
        "playerLoc": "Pwoods"
    },
    {
        "playerId": "2",
        "playerLoc": "Shelter"
    },
    {
        "playerId": "3",
        "playerLoc": "Cemetery"
    }
]
```

Made an effort to use Boomlagoon.JSON, but worked out on 1 object only. 
I have discovered that I need to deserialize them on this list. 
All I need is getting data from each `JSON` object. How can this be done with `C#`?

```
public class player
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string playerLoc { get; set; }
    public string playerNick { get; set; }
}
```

Only first KeyValuePair returned.

```
IDictionary<string, object> players = Json.Deserialize(serviceData) as IDictionary<string, object>;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in players)
{
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
}
```

Comment: Try deserializing to an `IEnumerable`, such as a List `List<player> players = Json.Deserialize<player>(serviceData);` In truth each player in serviceData would be considered its own dictionary of keyvalue pairs, so each will be overwritten by the next that gets deserialized unless you deserialize to a collection.

Comment: I will try it out, man. Thanks.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I think the syntax would be `Json.Deserialize<List<player>>(serviceData)` since it's a list. Also, for the OP, just deserialize them to a list as already mentioned, when done, you can access the members of each object; why put them in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you get JSON looking like this
    [
        {
            "type": "qrcode",
            "symbol": [
                {
                    "seq": 0,
                    "data": "HelloWorld9887725216",
                    "error": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
To analyze JSON there's sense to make a JSON model looking like this

```
[System.Serializable]
public class QrCodeResult
{
    public QRCodeData[] result;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Symbol
{
    public int seq;
    public string data;
    public string error;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class QRCodeData
{
    public string type;
    public Symbol[] symbol;
}
```

Comment: Not really a thing I was looking for, but that approach worked out pretty well. Thx, dude.

Answer (score 0):

Player class:

```
public class Player
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string playerLoc { get; set; }
}
```

You can deseriliaze with:

```
List<Player> players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();

foreach(Player player in playerArray)
{

Player playerObject = new Player()


playerObject.playerId = player.playerId ;
 playerObject.playerLoc = player.playerLoc;
layerList.Add(playerObject)
}

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return serializer.Serialize(playerList);
```